# Using datarow tests is it possible to filter on TestCategory when building?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs

We just upgraded test framework from the old Microsoft one to the newer (MSTest.TestFramework and MSTest.TestAdapter) to be able to use the DataRow variant of testing.

It works fine locally to execute multiple tests from the same test case, but when building on our build server (TFS2018), I'm having trouble filtering each individual datarow as a different test category. We are developing new features and do not want the new test cases to be run in a regression suite.

```
[Priority(2), DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(true), TestCategory("NewTestCase")
[DataRow(false), TestCategory("Regression")]
public void TestCase1(bool flag)
{
    ...
}
```

When running my build where test filter criteria is set to "TestCategory=Regression" I don't want the DataRow with the "NewTestCase" test category to be run or shown in build.

Comment: [Relevant](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/testcategory-and-datarow/465295).